# d3pie working in JS Bin, not in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, d3pie.js

I am currently trying to run sample code from d3pie on my browser before I start putting in my own data/editing it up. When I copy paste it to JS Bin, whether it be on Firefox or Chrome, it does work. This is how the code looks:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="pieChart"></div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.4/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/benkeen/d3pie/master/d3pie/d3pie.min.js">   </script>



<script>

   var randomval = 50;
   var pie = new d3pie("pieChart", {
"header": {
"title": {
"text": "Lots of Programming Languages",
"fontSize": 24,
"font": "open sans"
},
"subtitle": {
"text": "A full pie chart to show off label collision detection and resolution.",
"color": "#999999",
"fontSize": 12,
"font": "open sans"
},
"titleSubtitlePadding": 9
},
"footer": {
"color": "#999999",
"fontSize": 10,
"font": "open sans",
"location": "bottom-left"
},
"size": {
"canvasWidth": 590,
"pieOuterRadius": "90%"
},
"data": {
"sortOrder": "value-desc",
"content": [
{
"label": "JavaScript",
"value": randomval,
"color": "#2484c1"
},
{
"label": "Ruby",
"value": 218812,
"color": "#0c6197"
},
{
"label": "Java",
"value": 157618,
"color": "#4daa4b"
}
]
},
"labels": {
"outer": {
"pieDistance": 32
},
"inner": {
"hideWhenLessThanPercentage": 3
},
"mainLabel": {
"fontSize": 11
},
"percentage": {
"color": "#ffffff",
"decimalPlaces": 0
},
"value": {
"color": "#adadad",
"fontSize": 11
},
"lines": {
"enabled": true
},
"truncation": {
"enabled": true
}
},
"effects": {
"pullOutSegmentOnClick": {
"effect": "linear",
"speed": 400,
"size": 8
}
},
"misc": {
"gradient": {
"enabled": true,
"percentage": 100
}
}
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, when I copy paste this code into a HTML file and run that HTML file on Chrome or Firefox, no chart is being seen!! I changed the script of d3pie.min.js to just:

```
<script src="d3pie.min.js></script>
```

and am positive that I have the d3pie.min.js file saved correctly locally. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is and why it is not being displayed properly on a browser. Has anyone had this sort of issue in the past? Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Nope, it is just a blank screen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.4/d3.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.4/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That seemed to fix my initial problem, thanks! I am still having an issue however as in JS Bin, I am reading a document and am alerting that data, which does work. However, it does not work in the browser. This is how I am calling it inside JS Bin:

`$.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/"
               + "6a76aa9d2921350c9d53/raw/"
               + "1864137bfd2eb62705bd0e71175048a28b3253e6/abc.txt", function(data)
{
alert(data);
});`

Am I calling it wrong in the browser? It worked in JS Bin and had the https as well. @potatopeelings

Comment: Just add  `$.support.cors = true;` before your $.get call. I assume you've already included jQuery (didn't see that in the HTML in your question). Cheers!

Comment: I added that line but it's still not alerting anything for some reason. And yes, I did include jQuery like this:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$.support.cors = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
           $.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/"
               + "6a76aa9d2921350c9d53/raw/"
               + "1864137bfd2eb62705bd0e71175048a28b3253e6/abc.txt", function(data)
{
alert(data);

});
    });
  </script>`

Comment: It was because when I Was calling jQuery, I forgot to add the http: :P Thanks for the help though!

Comment: :-) Glad you got that figured out. Cheers!